# Does this conversation/exchange of words make sense?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-choice, mandarin, usage

Person A: 你快乐吗? - Are you happy?

Person B: 我常常是。-I often am.

Person A: 有意思。- Interesting.

Person B: 你没有不对。- You are not wrong.

Would this exchange make sense to a 中国人？ Does it sound natural and are the translations correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"你快乐吗?" *sounds normal enough*

"我常常是" *sounds too 'English' . Native Chinese would reply: "我常常都很快乐"*

"有意思" *sounds normal enough, but it implies the answer is somewhat unexpected*

The last line has the most problem:

> "你没有不对" means "you didn't do anything wrong"

For "you are not wrong" in this context, native Chinese would say: " 你说得对" or "你说得没错". Both mean "you are right"

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I fail to see why that is 'interesting'. I'd put it like this:

A: Are you happy? 你开心吗？
B: I often am. 我通常很开心。
A: (That is) Interesting. 这很有趣。
B: You're not wrong. 你没说错。
（Me: Really? Why? That's very normal.真的？为什么？ 这很正常丫！）

Or, alternatively:
A: Are you Happy? 你是开心果？
B: No, I'm Sleepy? 不，我是瞌睡虫。

Comment: It would make sense if A thought B 's life is miserable--  A: "你快乐吗?" B: "我常常都很快乐" A "有意思, 你没钱，没工作，没女朋友，但是你说你常常都很快乐..." B: "你说得没错, 我没钱，没工作，没女朋友, 但是我常常都很快乐"